# Insert data into SQL Server using file txt

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to insert data from a `.txt` file into SQL Server database, but I have a problem: it only insert the first line from my file, it doesn't insert the second and the next line.

How can I solve this?

```cs
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@path_reporttext);

if ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path_reporttext);
    int countOfLines = lines.Count();
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');

    foreach (string linee in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(linee);
        FingerLog.InsertData(fields[0].ToString(), fields[1].ToString(), "NULL", DateTime.Now, "NULL", fields[5].ToString());
    }
}
```

This is my `.txt` file:

[image]

This is what I want in SQL Server:

[image: This is my txt file]

Comment: Please post your text file _as text_ so those wishing to test your code can copy and paste it.  Also, `string[] fields = line.Split(',');` should be inside your `foreach` and splitting `linee`.

Comment: `string[] fields = line.Split(',');`  That's only the first line.  And why are you using _both_ a StreamReader and File.ReadAllLines()?  You should use one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `StreamReader` and reading a single line from it, then reading the entire file into a `string[]` and looping over those lines.  In the loop, you are inserting data from `fields`, which was created *outside* the loop by `Split()`ing that first line from the `StreamReader`, not the current line.

Try this instead...

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path_reporttext);
//int countOfLines = lines.Count();

foreach (string linee in lines)
{
    string[] fields = linee.Split(',');

    Console.WriteLine(linee);
    FingerLog.InsertData(fields[0], fields[1], "NULL", DateTime.Now, "NULL", fields[5]);
}
```

I also removed the `.ToString()` calls on the elements of `fields` because they are redundant.